# ¿Por qué existe la etiqueta [object] y [objeto] si ambas son casi lo mismo?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Creo que hay una etiqueta repetida, veo innecesario que hayan dos etiquetas con el mismo significado. La etiqueta [object](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object) y la etiqueta [objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objeto) tienen casi la misma definición:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La única deferencia es que "objeto" al principio dice

> En el paradigma de programación orientada a objetos (POO, o bien OOP en inglés),

Entonces:

- ¿Por que hay una etiqueta en inglés si el foro es para hispanohablantes y hay otra igual (hasta mejor en español)?
- ¿Si [objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objeto) está más completa, por qué todavía existe [object](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object)?
- ¿Cómo se crean las etiquetas?

Gracias por leer :)

Comment: propongo cambiar el título a: juntemos las etiquetas. Se ha hecho con frecuencia en el pasado y es algo que los moderadores pueden hacer muy rápidamente. Lo mismo puedes añadir también [meta-tag:sinónimos-de-etiquetas]

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' todas a objeto no?

Comment: @gbianchi yo creo que sí, pero dejando [tag:object] como sinónimo. También sería bueno mirar qué hay usando estas etiquetas, pues lo mismo en muchas no está aportando nada. Pero bueno, sería otro tema.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' y eso es como cuando ponen POO porque es un lenguaje orientado a objetos.. muy pocas veces aporta algo...

Comment: eso fue rápido, @gbianchi, ¡gracias!